# Шрифт в TextMeshPro выглядит неправильно. Unity

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-ui

Для отображения текста использую TextMeshPro. У меня есть скачанный шрифт - Quanelas. Создаю для него TMP Font Asset через Font Asset Creator. Выбираю его но текст на моем TMP не меняется. Вот как выглядят цифры, например:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот как они должны выглядеть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему так происходит?

UPD: еще заметил, что в SubMesh шрифт стоит дефолтный, несмотря ни на что:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это происходит поскольку в созданном ассете-шрифтов нет нужных символов. Сабмеш - это скрипт нужный как раз для "отсутствующих" символов. Т.е. "если в указанном шрифте нет символов, то взять их из шрифта, указанного в сабмеше".

Скорее всего, цифровых глифов нет либо в том шрифте, который вы скачали, либо в ассете, который вы из него создали. Там при создании ассета можно выбирать наборы символов, которые вам нужны. Попробуйте выбрать кастомный список, вписать туда все числа и создать ассет.

Если с созданным таким образом ассетом числа появятся, значит проблема в том наборе символов, который вы использовали для предыдущего ассета. Можно вообще создать текстовик со всеми нужными символами и использовать его.

Comment: а какой Unicode Range для обычных цифр?

Comment: @Some_Person, не могу подсказать. Я всегда использовал "Символы из файлы", когда мне нужны были только конкретные)